# Node js $like query

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I wanted to achieve the ff. result on the sample image below. names with don should come out first and not jal as you can see on the screenshot. thanks

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkpE0.png)

## my current query

```
const searchQuery = {
      query: {
        $or: [
          { firstName: { $like: text } },
          { email: { $like: text } },
          // { 'employee.name': { $like: text } },
        ],
        status: 1,
        $sort: {
          firstName: 0
        },
        $limit: 5,
      }
    };
```

Comment: can you provide an example

Answer (score 0):

You can try [select2](https://select2.org/searching) plugin as a frontend, select2 uses internal "matching" to match search terms with results.

hope this helps.